# Error with Nginx/Gunicorn connect() to .sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx

I have done endless searching and attempts at fixing this issue, but this refuses to work.

Im using `Python 3.3/Gunicorn/Nginx`, when I try to run my site I get:

```
[error] 904#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/user/project/project.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: mysite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "mysite.com", referrer: "mysite.com/"
```

I was following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) completely, after several attempts of reattempting it all I am still receiving this error.

Here is what my configs look like:
**upstart script in `/etc/init`**

```
description "Gunicorn application server running myproject"

    start on runlevel [2345]
    stop on runlevel [!2345]

    respawn          #respawn this on reboot
    setuid user        #set as unix user 'jd' to run as
    setgid www-data  #user used by nginx

    env PATH=/home/user/project/projectenv/bin
    chdir /home/user/project
    exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi
```

the permissions on this file:

```
    chmod 644
    user user 373 Dec 13 09:21 homepage.conf
```

**nginx

```
config**
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name mysite.com;

        error_log /home/user/project/nginx_error.log info;

        root /home/user/project/projectenv;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock;
        }

    }
```

if i run `nginx -t` in the directory of the nginx config, it shows:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
```

**permissions of `/home/user/project/project.sock;`**

```
srwxrwx--- 1 user www-data
```

**my `wsgi.py` file** (as outlined in the article) contains:

```
from homepage import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

The interesting thing is, if I try out this command:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi
```

outlined [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04#testing-gunicorn-39-s-ability-to-serve-the-project)

Gunicorn starts up fine, and I can view my page perfectly.

The real question is, what is the issue causing this to not run from an `ubuntu startup script` in `/etc/init`? ... because the script is running fin

Does anyone see anything?

Thank you.

Comment: "connection refused" means just this: you are attempting to connect to a host:port at which nothing is listening.

Comment: So, find out where you are connecting, then investigate if you're using incorrect info or something should be listening yet it doesn't.

Comment: How do you know for sure